# Is it correct to say "pas sans nous déplaire" instead of "pas pour nous déplaire"?

Tags: expressions

> La fenêtre de la chambre offre une vue dégagée sur la mer, ce qui **n'est pas sans nous déplaire**.

The use of the double negative, "pas" and "sans", pulled me up short. As if you could ever have something to complain about a panoramic view of the ocean! Shouldn't you say instead:

> La fenêtre de la chambre offre une vue dégagée sur la mer, ce qui **n'est pas pour nous déplaire**.

I wonder if the speaker lumped it together with similar expressions such as "qui n'est pas sans nous rappeler"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say *pas sans nous déplaire* is likely a mistake and means the opposite of  *pas pour nous déplaire*.

This mistake can be put in parallel with :

> Vous n'êtes pas sans savoir...

which clearly means :

> Vous savez...

unlike this bogus sentence that is sometimes heard:

> [Vous n'êtes pas sans ignorer...](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/vous-netes-pas-sans-ignorer-que)